# how to update tableview cells using array from nsobject class

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

When I try to receive data from detail view controller, the master view controller is not added a new cell. I want to update the table view in master view controller based on the array in the detail view-controller. Also cancel button is not work more than one time

This is the master view controller code for save and cancel button.

```
 (void)detailControllerSaved:(DetailViewController *)controller {

    if ([self.presentedViewController isEqual:controller]) {

        [self.moviesToDisplay addObject:controller.detailItem];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                 completion:nil];

        // it's a modal view
    } else {

        // it's a navigation view
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        self.moviesToDisplay[indexPath.row] = controller.detailItem;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

(void)detailControllerCanceled:(DetailViewController *)controller {

    if ([self.presentedViewController isEqual:controller]) {

        // it's a modal view
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                 completion:nil];

    } else {

        // it's a navigation view
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

This is my array list 



(void) loadSampleContent {

    NSArray *movies = @[
                        [Films movieWithGenre:@"Comedy" title:@"LittleMan " date:@"2006" rate:@"7.5"],

    self.moviesToDisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:movies];
}



and this is the code in the detail view controller 




(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if(self.detailItem) {
        self.movieTitle.text = self.detailItem.movieTitle;
        self.genreField.text = self.detailItem.movieGenre;
        self.movieRate.text = self.detailItem.movieRate;
        self.yearOfMovie.text = self.detailItem.movieDate;
    }
}

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 (IBAction)Save:(id)sender {
    self.detailItem =
    [Films movieWithGenre:self.genreField.text title:self.movieTitle.text date:self.yearOfMovie.text rate:self.movieRate.text];
    [self.delegate detailControllerSaved:self];
}
 (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate detailControllerCanceled:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed reload table after received data from Detail viewcontroller. Try add reload tableview in mastercontroller in this code:

if ([self.presentedViewController isEqual:controller]) {

```
    [self.moviesToDisplay addObject:controller.detailItem];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:nil];

    // it's a modal view
}
```

Hope this help!